# pyMySQL set connection character set

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, pymysql

I'm developing a fairly straightforward web app using Flask and MySQL.

I'm struggling with unicode. Users sometimes paste stuff that they copied from Word and it's falling over with the old smart quotes `u'\u201c'`.

A little bit of investigation shows that the connection I have to MySQL is using the `Latin1` charset (seems to be the default).

How can I specify for it to use unicode for its connection?

I'm using pyMySQL, which purports to be a drop-in replacement for MySQLdb. MySQLdb defines a `set_character_set(self, charset)` function for `connection` objects, but pyMySQL doesn't (I get an error if I try).

Comment: You could try a raw query for every connection you have stating `SET NAMES UTF8`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I worked it out by poking around in the [pyMySQL source](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) (I had tried, but couldn't find the right place!).

You can specify it when you create the connection:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                       user='username',
                       passwd='password',
                       db='database',
                       charset='utf8')
```

Solved my problem.

Comment: I was trying to use pymysql with sqlalchemy, so the fix for me was to change the url to `mysql+pymysql://user_name@host_name/database_name?charset=utf8mb4` ; this answer helped a lot!